# Providing variables outside of ng-view

Tags: angularjs

So, I have an HTML page, /profile#IDGoesHere which is tied an an ng-app. The ng-app has three columns (with Bootstrap) and the middle of which is utilising Angular's ng-view.

So it's something like this:

/profile#IDGoesHere (and within it):

- All Activity
- Posts
- Likes
- Dislikes
  etc

The href links are set on the HTML page outside of the ng-view so when I go into the /profile#IDGoesHere page, I set the userID into a variable using a service. Like below:

```
profileApp.service('globalParams', function() {
var profileID = '';
var user = {};

return {
    getProfileID: function() {
        return profileID;
    },
    setProfileID: function(value) {
        profileID = value;
    }
};
});
```

I pass the 'globalParams' service into each controller as I need to access the profileID in order to make further calls to get the specific data for the user.

My Angular Router looks like this:

```
 $routeProvider
.when('/profile:id', {
    templateUrl : 'partial/profile/feed.html',
    controller  : 'mainController',
    resolve:{
        myData: ['$http', function($http){
            return $http.get('/session');
        }]
    }
})
.when('/posts', {templateUrl: 'partial/profile/posts.html',         controller: 'postsController'})
.when('/agreed', {templateUrl: 'partial/profile/likes.html',       controller: 'likesController'})
.when('/disagreed', {templateUrl: 'partial/profile/dislikes.html', controller: 'dislikesController'})
.when('/comments', {templateUrl: 'partial/profile/comments.html',   controller: 'commentsController'});
});
```

Now the problem, the links to Posts, Likes, Dislikes etc do not have the profileID in them as they are set when you go to the main route, /profile#IDGoesHere.

This works when I am on the page and keep navigating by using the 'globalParams' service however, if I were to refresh the page when I was on one of the sub-pages, the data is lost.

Note: I can't make the whole page to reload which is why I used the ng-view. I could fix this by doing that but it will defeat the purpose of a single page application.

Does anyone have a good idea on this? Been pulling my hair but feel I am missing something very obvious.

Thanks in advance

Edit: as it was causing some confusion, I have added a screenshot to demonstrate how it looks like:
[image]

Comment: The answer is in the question: the routes should be /profile/:id/posts (for example). And this global params service should be removed.

Comment: Yes but that is essentially my problem. How do I pass :id to the href when it is outside of the ng-view?

Comment: The same way as anywhere else. By using the $routeParams service to get the ID.

Comment: The href for comments, likes, dislikes are "outside" of ng-view. The left pane, which has these sub-pages, are currently static links as the links are generated "before" I even have the value. This is why I created the "globalParams" service. Hope this clears it up

Comment: There is nothing to clear up on my side. Your service is used to know what the profileID is. This profileID should be in all URLs (and route definitions) that display something related to the profile. And once it's there, you have access to the profileID from anywhere in the app using the $routeParams service. Whether the links are inside or outside the ng-view doesn't matter.

Comment: I have edited my question for clarification and added a screenshot. The href itself is outside of the ng-view so I can't pull the params from the URL as there I can't put it in the URL in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed by attaching the whole < body > to a parent controller and under that controller, I used the $window.location.href and split the ID from URL and then added it to the service, which I could then add to the outer hrefs for my sub-pages, essentially making the sub-pages to have a routeParam as well